# How to loop through first n elements

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop through first n elements of the different arrays of different length to check if the number exists or not

```
a=[0,1,2,4,5]
count=0
for i in range(3):
  if a[i]==4:
    count+=1
if count>=1:
  print(count)
else:
  print('not in array')
```

I have tried this as well

```
for in range a[:3]:
```

The problem is if array length lower than n, here in this case 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about `count` with list slicing?

```
a[:n].count(4)
```

This handles end conditions automatically, so there's no problem like array length lower than `n`.

---

If you need just a membership check, use membership operator `in` on a set (as shown by other answerer):

```
4 in set(a[:n])
```

Comment: @yatu, OP is printing count in the end, I guess?

Comment: `bool(a[:3].count(4))`

Comment: Austin, try this: `print(a.count(4))`

Answer (score 2):

To check if an element is in an array, you could use a set:

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,4,5]
>>> 4 in set(a[:3])
False
>>> 3 in set(a[:3])
True
```

Comment: If you make a new set each time that defeats its purpose and you can just use `in` with the original list.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the `len()` function within the for loop:

```
a=[0,1,2,4,5]
count=0
for i in range(len(a)):
  if a[i]==4:
    count+=1
if count>=1:
  print(count)
else:
  print('not in array')
```

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that. It increments the count if number is in array after the nth index. a[:n].count(4) worked. Thanks for the reply